# VBA Trying to make a function that will randomly assign names to each other without repeating, getting Compile error: Expected array

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a button that will take a list of names and match them up with each other over multiple weeks without matching the same people up twice. With the code I have written I get an error that says "Compile Error: Expected Array"

Below is the code that I have so far. Any help would be appreciated

```
Sub nameMatcher()

Dim column As Integer
Dim cellsDown As Integer
Dim randomNumber As Integer
Dim names As String
Dim i As Byte
Dim arI As Byte
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim numNames As Integer

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
cellsDown = 3

column = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="What meeting number is this for?", Type:=1)

numNames = Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) - 1
i = 1

Do While i <= numNames
randomNum:
    randomNumber = Application.RandBetween(2, numNames + 1)
    For arI = LBound(names) To UBound(names)
        If names(arI) = Cells(randomNumber, 1).Value Then
            GoTo randomNum
        End If
    Next arI
    names(i) = Cells(randomNumber, 1).Value
    i = i + 1
Loop

Worksheet
For arI = LBound(names) To UBound(names)

    Cells(cellsDown, column) = names(arI)
    cellsDown = cellsDown + 1

Next arI

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You declared names as a string not a string array. You also don't seem to be populating names before getting its upper and lower bounds so that will probably error.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Warcupine suggested - your main problem is your not declaring your array as a variant or an array. Both will work, but I think it's simplest to declare as a variant and then assign your column of values to create the array

Change

```
Dim names As String
```

To

```
Dim names As Variant
```

Then after the line (are you subtracting 1 to ignore header??)

```
numNames = Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) - 1
```

Add this line to fill in your array (assuming top row is ignored header)

```
names = Range("A2:A" & numNames+1)
```

And then you'll have to change all your array references to use the second dimension as 1

So `names(arI)` becomes `names(arI,1)`
and `names(i)` becomes `names(i,1)`